# Calculation issue in C++

Tags: c++, function, algebra

So in this program i am trying to print out the standard deviation of a set of numbers the user enters in. The formula to calculate standard deviation is correct (or as correct as it needs to be) so that is not the problem, but when i run the program everything goes well until the console prints out the results. It prints that totalStandardDeviation = nan

what exactly does than mean? is nan the same as nil? has it lost the value somehow and not been able to find it? thanks for any help you may provide.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double returnStandardDeviation(double x, int counter);
double total;

int userInput = 1;
int counter = 0;
double x;
double x1;
double x2;

double standardDeviation;
double totalStandardDeviation;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << "Please enter a list of numbers. When done enter the number 0 \n";
    cin >> userInput;

    while (userInput != 0)                         // As long as the user does not enter 0, program accepts more data
    {
        counter++;
        x = userInput;
        returnStandardDeviation( x, counter);       // send perameters to function

        cout << "Please enter next number \n";
        cin >> userInput;
    }

    cout << "The standard deviation of your "
    << counter
    << " numbers is : "
    << returnStandardDeviation(x, counter);
    return 0;
}


double returnStandardDeviation(double x, int counter)
{
    x1 += pow(x,2);
    x2 += x;
    totalStandardDeviation = 0;
    totalStandardDeviation += (sqrt(counter * x1 - pow(x2,2))) / (counter * (counter - 1));
    return totalStandardDeviation;
}
```

Comment: As the function returns "not a number", your calculation can't be correct.

Comment: You also have a problem in `returnStandardDeviation` when you reset `totalStandardDeviation` *in every call*. It should only add to it in the function.

Comment: You need to provide the example input you use to get the error.

Comment: unused variables? you mean ones like "double x"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is wrong. You are either dividing by zero or taking the square root of a negative number.

Check your formula!

**Additional info:**

NaN is "Not a number". It is an IEEE floating point value that signals an invalid results, like log(-1), or sqrt(-4).

Additionally, know that Positive Infinity and Negative Infinity are also floating point values.

Comment: no, i have tested this out. Im testing with the numbers 65 and 50. I put breakpoints in the program to make sure i didn't divide by zero or anything funny like that.

Comment: @nfoggia ask yourself what `counter * (counter-1)` is when `counter == 1`. Then ask yourself what happens when that quantity is in the *denominator* of a fractional division.

Comment: that was the solution... didn't even notice that

Comment: So to fix this i simply added
    if (counter > 1)
before the equation

Comment: @nfoggia I suspected as much. Do yourself a favor and throw out all those unused globals. they make analyzing this problem a real bear.

Answer (score 1):

[NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) stands for "Not a number".

Comment: thank you. i cant seem to find why the equation results in "NaN" though

Answer (score 1):

[NaN](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) can e.g. be the result of:

```
- Dividing by zero
- Taking the square root of a negative number
```

In your function, both of these could happen. Division by zero e.g. when `counter` is <= 1; and `x1` and `x2` are uninitialized (`+=` adds the value on the right to their *current* value - which was never set, and is therefore random gibberish), which can easily lead to your function trying to take the square root of some value < 0.

Comment: I was able to put breakpoints in the program and it seems to set it to NaN while it is going through the function in the cout line

Comment: that sounds very unlikely. what is the input you give to `returnStandardDeviation`, what is it's return value? if you e.g. input 1 as `counter`, you will see NaN as result (1 * (1-1)) == 0 => division by zero

Answer (score 1):

This expression

```
counter * x1 - pow(x2,2)
```

can very easily yield a negative number. You then proceed to take its square root. This would result in a `nan`.

Next, this one

```
counter * (counter - 1)
```

yields `0` when `counter` is `1`. Dividing by zero gives `nan`.

Comment: As they are global variables, shouldn't they be initialized to zero?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, I had missed that. I am not used to reading stuff with globals in it any more.